# How to keep popover opened in safari extension

Tags: javascript, html, popover, safari-extension

For a project I'm building an safari extension. One part of the extension contains the popover part.

When someone clicks the extension toolbar button, a popover window scrolls down to display some information.

This is working as expected but now the following:

The plan is to make some sort of companion popover, so when the user clicks inside a webpage, some elements are selected and displayed in the popover.

The problem is the popover closes when one clicks next to the popover window while it should be left open.

Does anybody know a way to keep the popover window open while browsing pages?

There is a function on the window object:

window.onblur

Which fires an event when the popover closes. Is there a way to cancel the closing operation?

Comment: What happens if you `preventDefault()` on the `blur` event?

Comment: nothing unfortunately :(